# How Can I Display First 2 Paragraphs? And then Remaining Paragraphs? - PHP

Tags: php

I have 4 paragraphs of text in one string. Each paragraph is surrounded with `<p></p>`.

1. My first goal is to output the first 2 paragraphs.
2. My second goal it to output the remaining paragraphs somewhere else on the page. I could sometimes be dealing with strings containing more than 4 paragraphs.

I've searched on the web for anything already out there. There's quite a bit about displaying just the first paragraph, but nothing I could find about displaying paragraphs 1-2 and then the remaining paragraphs. Can anyone help here?

Not sure which to use if any, substr, strpos, etc.....?

EDIT - thanks for your answers, to clarify, the paragraphs don't contain HTML at the moment, but yes I will need the option to have HTML within each paragraph.

Comment: Load it into an HTML parser, such as DOMDocument - that class will give you plenty of flexibility. Read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Comment: If you would clarify your question with example paragraphs, that would be helpful. In particular, can they in themselves contain HTML tags?

Comment: To your edit, look at the `getInner` function from my answer, that will keep it working no matter the content within the `p` tag (except for maybe an embedded `p` within it. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use DOMDocument

Initialize with:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($myString);
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

If each can contains other HTML elements(or not), create a function:

```
function getInner(DOMElement $node) {
    $tmp = "";
    foreach($node->childNodes as $c) {
        $tmp .= $c->ownerDocument->saveXML($c);
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

and then use that function when needing the paragraph like so:

```
$p1 = getInner($p->item(0));
```

You can read more about [`DOMDocument` here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Is this correct? `$p = $dom->getElementsByTag('p');` should it be `getElementsByTagName()`? - BTW my PHP knowledge isn't too advanced.

Comment: Also I'm getting this error Jon `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in ` which refers to this line: `$p1 = getInner($p[0]);` - any ideas what's going wrong there?

Comment: I'm trying to get it working [here on PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q6g-ke5)

Comment: I'm sorry, I somehow forgot `Name` for that function, but you are correct.  Updated the code to correct values, and made use of using `DOMNodeList`sproperly ^^. [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gc5-jdp)  Quick look at change `getInner($p->item(index))` ^^

Comment: Thanks very much for the update Jon. Also `$dom = new DOMDocument;` needs to have parentheses I think? To read: `$dom = new DOMDocument();` I've published the code I ended up using [on PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6bi-fp5) - thanks for all your help.

Comment: In PHP5.4 at least it doesn't, though I didn't test in lower versions, but it defaults to a null constructor since one isn't required. ^^  And you are welcome!  Sorry I put in some misinformation the first time with accessing the elements. ^^

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression:

```
    $str = '<p style="color:red;"><b>asd</b>para<img src="afs"/>graph 1</p >
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        <p>paragraph 3</p>
        <p>paragraph 4</p>
            ';


   // preg_match_all('/<p.*>([^\<]+)<\/p\s*>/i',$str,$matches);
    //for inside html like a comment sais:
    preg_match_all('/<p[^\>]*>(.*)<\/p\s*>/i',$str,$matches);

    print_r($matches);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p style="color:red;"><b>asd</b>para<img src="afs"/>graph 1</p >
            [1] => <p>paragraph 2</p>
            [2] => <p>paragraph 3</p>
            [3] => <p>paragraph 4</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>asd</b>para<img src="afs"/>graph 1
            [1] => paragraph 2
            [2] => paragraph 3
            [3] => paragraph 4
        )

)
```

Comment: What about paragraphs containing other tags, such as `<em>` or `<img />`?

Comment: mmm... basically you are right but I don't think he ask for that

Comment: As the question stands, that is not clear at all (I've asked for clarification). Incidentally, regexps are generally not recommended for parsing HTML - [see why here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Comment: You are right ! - I edited my answer just for knowledge - but nevertheless the `DOMDocument` answer is the way to go...